# Change website text with python

Tags: python, html

This is my first StackOverflow post so please bear with me.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a simple program written in python which will change all of a certain html tag's content (ex. all `<h1>` or all `<p>` tags) to something else. This should be done on an **existing** web page which is currently open in a web browser.

In other words, I want to be able to automate the **inspect element** function in a browser which will then let me change elements however I wish. I know these changes will just be on my side, but that will serve my larger purpose.

I looked at Beautiful Soup and couldn't find anything in the documentation which will let me change the website as seen in a browser. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be greatly appreciative!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using javascript for this? Especially since you specify that it'll be client side.

Comment: I would like to do some outside-of-browser things as well with it, but would it be possible to pass output generated by js to python? I'm pretty new to js in general

Comment: The great thing about Javascript in this context is that it _already runs in the browser_. With Python, you'd have to do some stuff before; the easiest method would be if you could copy the URL from the browser into your Python program. Do you need to get the results of your program _back into the browser_ afterwards? Does this have to work on any computer or just on yours, which may have some sort of complicated setup to make this work? Please write a bit more about your problem and what you want to do. If it's really just changing some element's content, you're better of with Javascript.

Comment: Yes the results of the python program would eventually have to be displayed back in the browser. I think I'm going to explore javascript a bit more, not sure why I was so set on python from the outset

Comment: Have you taken a look at [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)?  From what I understood about what you're trying to do, I've done this using selenium.

Comment: Have you tried this: Try this:
https://towardsdatascience.com/controlling-the-web-with-python-6fceb22c5f08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about seems to be much more of the job of a browser extension. Javascript will be much more appropriate, as @brbcoding said. Beautiful Soup is for scraping web pages, not for modifying them on the client side in a browser. To be honest, I don't think you can use Python for that.